# starting a django project

Tags: python, django, windows

Im brand new to django and am wondering if i could get some help, Im working my way through the guide on the django website and have got to the point of starting a new project with `...\> django-admin startproject mysite` after running this command in the terminal I get back an error saying

```
django-admin : The term 'django-admin' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a     
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ django-admin
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (django-admin:String) [], CommandNotFoun  
   dException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Im not a huge fan of the windows terminal and try my best to understand the errors it throws at me but cant. could someone help me out with this please.

Comment: Have you installed Django (e.g. `pip install django`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create virtual env first

```
py -m venv venv
```

Then activate it by given command

```
venv\Scripts\Activate
```

Then install your django by below command

```
pip install django
```

after that create your project

```
django-admin startproject mysite
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/windows/#how-to-install-django-on-windows) and [guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial01/#writing-your-first-django-app-part-1).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not on windows myself but I reckon that error simply means you did not install Django (or Windows can't find it). Try doing `pip install django` as @Fiddling Bits mentioned (or `pipenv install django` if you use pipenv).

The Djangogirls installation guide seems very thorough and also includes instructions for Windows: https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/installation/